# Postgres doesn't use index even though it is created

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
Table Creation
accident_info
(
    accident_index varchar(20),
    first_road_class varchar(20),
    accident_severity varchar(20),
    date date,
    urban_or_rural_area varchar(20),
    weather_conditions varchar(40),
    year int,
    inscotland varchar(20)
);
```

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX index1 ON accident_info(accident_info.first_road_class , accident_info.date)

CREATE INDEX index2 ON accident_info(vehicle_info.age_band_of_driver)
```

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(accident_info.accident_index) as max, vehicle_info.make
FROM vehicle_info
INNER JOIN accident_info on vehicle_info.accident_index = accident_info.accident_index
WHERE vehicle_info.age_band_of_driver = '26 - 35' AND accident_info.first_road_class = 'A' AND accident_info.date > '2009-12-31' and accident_info.date < '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY make
ORDER BY max DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Even though I have created two indexes, Postgres doesn't use none of them. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a "simple" explain). [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: This appears to be missing the definition of `vehicle_info` and moreover the `index2` involves a mismatch between table and column. Please check this.

Comment: P.S. You will be much happier if you don't use reserved words like `date` as column names even when the can be correctly interpreted or escaped.

Comment: "`CREATE INDEX index2 ON accident_info(vehicle_info.age_band_of_driver)`" -- so you try to create an index on a table and a column of another table? I doubt Postgres would create such an index...

Comment: I am sure `index2` is meant to be on `vehicle_info` and that is just a typo. The question is unclear: **Which** index is not used? None of them? It is pretty normal for PostgreSQL not to use an index if the index doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your dataset is just too small to use index

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22057445)

Comment: @Andrew I think it's pretty clear to the question. Maybe the author's dataset is not big enough for postgreSQL to use Index. What other information do I need to provide to support this point...